# sql safe query from sql injection

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js, sql-injection

i have query with prepared statement and parameterized query. but still failed when it comes to sonarqube and gave query safe issue. i don't know what is not safe in my query

here is the code:

```
let { keyword } = req.query;
    const first_query = `
      SELECT hs_code, tree_id, CONCAT(hs_code, ' - ', tree_id)
      AS gabungan FROM referensi.v_btbmi_2022 vb
    `;
    const option =
      keyword.length < 1
        ? 'false'
        : '(tree_id ILIKE :keyword OR hs_code ILIKE :keyword)';

    if (keyword.length < 1) {
      res.status(400).json({
        code: "03",
        message: "data inputan tidak ada",
        data: [],
      });
      return;
    }

    const last_query = await db.query(
      first_query + ' WHERE LENGTH(hs_code) > 7 AND ' + option,
      {
        replacements: { keyword: `%${keyword}%` },
        type: db.QueryTypes.SELECT,
      },
    );
```

i am new to backend development and think that this query is safe enought. how to improve the query so it really safe and can pass sonarqube?